# How to draw smooth lines in actionscript 3 (Flash)

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I draw smooth lines with actionscript 3 (using flex 4)?

I mean: I do something like this:

```
        var grap:Graphics =  this.display.graphics;
        grap.lineStyle(8, 0xFF0000, 1, true, "normal", CapsStyle.ROUND);
        grap.moveTo(180,330);
        grap.lineTo(200,130);
```

But the result looks like this:
 
http://sub.ited.nl/try/ :( 
The edges of the lines are very crispy, how can I improve this?
Especially when drawing the line through a Tween, it looks like a drunken man walking on the sidewalks ;)...

The tween code for drawing the line:

```
        var grap:Graphics =  this.display.graphics;
        grap.lineStyle(8, 0xFF0000, 1, true, "normal", CapsStyle.ROUND);
        grap.moveTo(220,330);
        new Tween(this, [220, 330], [240, 130]);
```

And in the onTweenUpdate method:

```
        this.display.graphics.lineTo(values[0], values[1]);
```

Please some advice on this?

BTW: how can best remove the default background of the flash object ? (the grey background).
I have this in my index.mxml:

```
    <mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="600" 
addedToStage="start()" styleName="plain" backgroundImage="{null}">
```

But I see a flickering often (in development mode), which means I first see the default  grey background and then a white one...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Incidentally you might want to make a new question about the background thing, tagged as "Flex" - since that gray background is drawn by the flex framework, not Flash itself. The "real" background of Flash itself is determined by how you embed the SWF (i.e. it's a parameter to your `object` and `embed` tags, if you're writing HTML).

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason not to, in each iteration, blank out the line's progress so far and re-draw it? As in:

```
// inside tween update
displayObj.graphics.clear();
displayObj.graphics.moveTo(180,330);
displayObj.graphics.lineTo(values[0]);
// i.e. only the end point is tweened
```

In your current code you're actually drawing lots of individual lines, so anything you did to improve the smoothness would depend delicately on the internals of how Flash renders, so you're probably better off redrawing the whole line each frame.

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing that out, complete forgot that.. :(...
The animated version looks better now (I updated the version online in the above link).
But still: how can I make the edges more smooth?  Or is this the best I can get? Or does it depend on the display (I am on a 1920x1200 HD display)